# How to use R language to cross-verify neural network model?

Tags: r, keras, cross-validation

```
model = keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 180, activation = "tanh", input_shape = in_dim) %>%    
  layer_dense(units = 150, activation = "tanh")  %>%
  layer_dense(units = 120, activation = "elu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 80, activation = "relu")  %>% 
  layer_dense(units = out_dim, activation = "linear") 

model %>% compile(
  loss = "mse",
  optimizer = "adam")

model %>% summary()

set.seed(23659545)
system.time(history <- model %>% fit(xtrain_CL, ytrain_CL,
                                     epochs = 100, batch_size=50, verbose = 1))
scores = model %>% evaluate(xtrain_CL, ytrain_CL, verbose = 0)
print(scores)
```

The neural network model is built using the Keras package of the R language. How to verify the model accuracy by cross-validation?
The purpose is to know how to automatically adjust the parameters of the neural network?
Very sincerely consult each scholar!

Comment: If you want to fine tune your model parameters you can use [R interface to Keras Tuner](https://eagerai.github.io/kerastuneR/)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?